# HasActivityInjector не найден

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger2

Я использую dagger 2.24. И он не находит HasActivityInjector, если изпользовать 2.18 то все норм, может в новой версии он по другому называется? 
Вот мой градл:

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24'
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.24"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.24"
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.24'
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.24"
```

Comment: https://twitter.com/rdshapiro/status/1154703987930738688

Comment: @Komdosh можно поподробнее?

Comment: не, я сам не понял, просто решил что это может вам помочь в поиске

Comment: @Komdosh разобрался

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если Вы используете версию 2.23 или новее. Вам надо использовать интерфейс HasAndroidInjector и написать следующий код

```
override fun androidInjector(): AndroidInjector<Any> = androidInjector

@Inject 
lateinit var androidInjector : DispatchingAndroidInjector<Any>
```

P.S. в андройде новичок, так что отвественость не беру